# Connecting Webcam to remote computer

Tags: webcam, remote-desktop

I have connected a webcam and mic in my PC. From that PC using mstsc I connected to another PC. Unlike keyboard and mouse which I am able to use in remote computer I am unable to use my webcam and mic. I am working in an environment where no new software can be installed. Please help me to write a code to share the webcam and mic connected in a PC with remote PC.

Comment: Is there any other way(without installing a new software) to make the local webcam and mic recognize in remote PC.

Comment: So you want to be able to use the webcam connected to a machine from a remote machine?

Comment: No sir, do we need to enable anything like any option in  mstsc?

Comment: My office communicator in remote machine says no web cam connected

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question,Yes I want to be able to use the webcam connected to a machine from a remote machine

Comment: Not to judge, but that sounds really creepy.  You want to turn on a webcam attached to someone else's computer and watch them?